# Combination - Ordering Boy Scouts

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many different ways can 9 distinct boy scouts be arranged in a 3 × 3 formation? In such a formation, there are 3 scouts in the ﬁrst row, 3 in the second, and 3 in the third. Two formations are the same if in every row, both formations contain the same three scouts in the same order.

I think it's 9 permute 3, 6 permute 3, 3 permute 3 multiplied together = 9! but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but doesn't the equality criterion mean that the $3 \times 3$ grid is equivalent to a linear ordering?

Comment: Yes even I feel this is equivalent to linear ordering and hence a total of $9!$ ways

Comment: The OP used correct though longer than necessary reasoning to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

One may arbitrarily define an ordering of the grid; something like:

```
 1 | 2 | 3
---+---+---
 4 | 5 | 6
---+---+---
 7 | 8 | 9
```

After an order is defined, you may rephrase the question like this: "in how many different ways can 9 distinct boy scouts be arranged in places 1,...,9?"

One thing about math is abstractions; for example, it wouldn't matter if you'd arrange **boy scouts** or **girl scouts** or **dolphins**, right? Boy scouts are just an example, a representative of the class of all things that can be distinguished. And one thing about combinatoric questions is finding a specific representative ("example") which hides the real (and usually simple) truth behind it.

In your case, the so-called grid just hides the simpler 9-places line. Similarly, one could ask "in how many different ways can 9 distinct boy scouts be arranged in a car with 2 front seats, 4 mid seats, and 3 back seats". Or whatever.